# jQuery Layouts with Drag and Drop

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, html

Ideally, what I'd like to do is have some layouts with designated spots that allow certain kinds of media to be dragged and dropped in those spots.

What recommendation do you have to accomplishing such a task? Should I just stick to the jQuery UI, or are there frameworks or plug-ins out there that would be better suited for the task?

Here is an example layout. Each section accepts a certain kind of content (that's all custom programming):
[image]

Comment: Don't worry about how the media get's connected... I'm just trying to accomplish the drag and drop interface. Each section would be limited to what type of content will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI Sortable, Draggable, and/or Droppable should provide all the functionality you need.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: Chris, thanks for responding. Take a look at the image I just uploaded. Gives a little more depth into what I'm looking to accomplish in the end.

Comment: Are you wanting to actually have the user drag the media from their desktop into the respective spaces? Otherwise where is the media coming from?

Comment: yiu have to refer this link
http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html

Comment: No no.. don't worry about how or what the actual media is... I just need to accomplish the interface.

Comment: Then yeah you can pull this off in jQuery UI no problem.